# How do I select a single row for each unique combination of multiple columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table/Data/SQL example: [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6dd62/1)

```
SELECT
  name,
  p1,
  p2,
  MIN(o1) as o1,
  MIN(o2) as o2
  FROM LOCS l
  GROUP BY l.name, l.p1, l.p2
  ORDER BY name asc
```

The current SQL I've come up with returns the correct data, but the actual table has 100+ columns and is constantly going to change so there is no way to do MIN() on each column.

I need to select a single row for each combination of "name", "p1", and "p2".

Comment: It is unclear what are you asking

Comment: How do you define "first row"?

Comment: This can be done and isn't difficult, but as @GordonLinoff says above, we need to know what makes a row "first".

Comment: In particular "the first row" is unclear, and "there is no way to do MIN() on each column" is unclear. Calling "MIN" for each column seems not only possible, but even easy. Does it not meet the requirements?

Comment: By "first" i meant the first row entered into the database. @GordonLinoff's answer meets the requirements.

Comment: You have to have something to define the row. By definition a table is an unordered set. Without a column that defines the insert order you can't determine the inserted order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to select to select the "first" row in a grouping, then you can use `row_number()` -- assuming you have a way of defining "first".

For instance, if the `o1` column specifies the ordering, the following gives the row for a particular `name`, `p1`, and `p2` combination with the lowest value of `o1`:

```
SELECT l.*
FROM (SELECT l.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name, p1, p2 ORDER BY o1) as seqnum
      FROM LOCS l
     ) l
WHERE seqnum = 1
ORDER BY name asc;
```